# Configuring ethernet comunication on Renesas R7FA6M3AH3CHP

Tags: c, ethernet, renesas-rx

I'm working with Renesas RA6M3 family and I'm having a hard time configuring ethernet communication using e2 studio. Examples that I've found are either for different microcontrollers or obsolete. There's no need for higher layers at this stage, the goal is to test the hardware so I'm doing it on bare metal. If anyone can help with the basics here it would be splendid.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, it's an operating system question. If it's Linux, ask in [linux.se].

Comment: @Barmar Actually I think this is a question about programming a microcontroller. It fits either here or on https://electronics.stackexchange.com. You might get better results on electronics there since people are more familiar with microcontrollers, but I don't think it's actually off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: However, the problem with this question is there's no actual question.